# Oracle UPDATE as a inner query inside a where clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to insert some values to a table based on the number of updates made by the same query.

An example queries I tried is as follows.

```
SELECT column1 column2 
  FROM table_A 
 WHERE (UPDATE table_B 
           SET column3= "?" 
         WHERE column3 = "?" 
       RETURN "UPDATED ROW COUNT") > 10
```

There can be many other ways to do this. But I explicitly want the update to execute on within the WHERE clause. This is to be used for a ethical hacking scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will get `ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query`

> Cause:  DML operation like insert, update, delete or select-for-update
>           cannot be performed inside a query or under a PDML slave.
>
> Action: Ensure that the offending DML operation is not performed or
>           use an autonomous transaction to perform the DML operation within
>           the query or PDML slave.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's Basically what I wanted to know. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it the way you describe. You can use the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` implicit cursor attribute in a PL/SQL block as shown.

```
 DECLARE
 ct NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_B SET column3 = 20 WHERE column3 = 40;
  ct := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  INSERT INTO table_A
  SELECT 1 column1 , 2 column2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ct;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks! ... Is there any Insert or update query that can be run inside a where clause.  As I have mentioned above this is for some Ethical hacking scene. There are some queries in a program of a friend of mine that I can send queries from the view to get added to the SQL. Just want to figure out whether a exploit is possible.

Comment: You are welcome!. I liked both yours and your friend's curiosity. However I  am not aware of any such "Ethical"  practices. I am just a stupid common man!!

Comment: Ha ha.. `\- (' | ' ) _/` ... I'm serious. This will never be used for any sort of crime.. Just checking it as the customer is very curious about the security of the program. Thanks again ..